# GIT sharing configuration data

Tags: git

I just started using GIT for my versioning and I want to program some tools that work on top of it. Here is my question:

Which information in the .git/config is shared to a remote repo? Is any? Is there a special way to push information to that repo?

The reason I am asking is that I would like to add a "unique stamp" to the config of a repo. Also the remote repo and everybody pulling that project should have the stamp. Is that possible?

If not, is there any other way to identify a repository? Having a .git folder, I want to decide whether this git repo is the same as a previously specified remote repo (the same means created by pulling the remote repo, changes are okay, of course).

Answer (score 2):

Nothing in the config file is transported as part of a repository.

You might find Git's [notes](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-notes.html) facility useful, though.